# 1099 MISC for elder care? She isn't required to file a return

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

If I received income from an elderly relative for elder care yet she does not file a tax return is it possible to obtain a 1099-MISC for that income I earned?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Why do you need 1099MISC? How much money did you earn?

Comment: Do you *want* one or are you afraid you might get one?

Comment: I am looking for more earned income for the purpose of contributing the max to my IRA.  I have several employers that did not supply me with 1099-MISC forms and they didn't because they aren't reporting what they paid me as it was under $600.  However, I'd still like to claim the income.

Comment: Update: as of 2020 this would be 1099-NEC instead of 1099-MISC. But an individual is not required to file any 1099's unless operating a trade or business; being old is definitely not a business, and I don't think you'll get far claiming it's a trade.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't receive a 1099, just report it using 1040 schedule C.  The IRS is happy to believe you when you tell them you earned some extra income--no need to twist their arm.

[Source at the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Miscellaneous-Income)

Comment: (1) link dead, and the website has changed so I can't find a good replacement (2) not always; if you claim Earned Income Credit (EIC or EITC) with child/ren, up to about $15k adding income grows the (refundable) credit faster than tax motivating people to fake income, and Schedule C is the safest way because IRS can't verify with third-party reporting. The VITA program, which focusses on 'moderate' income taxpayers, specifically trains the volunteers to be skeptical of taxpayers giving undocumented round-number 'self-employment' income -- and EIC is the main lowincome audit trigger.